# Multiple lattice plots with gridExtra

Tags: r, lattice

There is very convenient way of plotting multiple graphs and that's with gridExtra - `grid.arrange`:

```
grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,plot3,plot4,plot5,plot6,plot7,plot8,plot9, ncol=3)
```

The above command draws 3x3 graphs in one window.

Now, I'm using my own lattice setup to draw unique lines etc. via

```
trellis.par.set(my.setup)
```

However using the grid.arrange command for plotting multiple plots won't pass on the setup as the output plots are in default colours.

So the question is how to pass on the `my.setup` onto grid.arrange or alternatively how to plot easily multiple graphs in one go for lattice.

EDIT: Reproducible example:

```
Data <- data.frame(Col1=rnorm(10,0,1),Col2=rexp(10,2),Col3=rnorm(10,2,2),Col4=runif(10,0,2), 
       Time=seq(1,10,1))

trellis.par.set(col.whitebg()) 
newSet <- col.whitebg() 
newSet$superpose.symbol$col <- c("blue3","orange2","gray1","tomato3")
newSet$superpose.symbol$pch <- 1
newSet$superpose.symbol$cex <- 1
newSet$superpose.line$col <- c("blue3","orange2","gray1","tomato3")
trellis.par.set(newSet)

Plot1 <- xyplot(Col1+Col2~Time, Data, type="spline")
Plot2 <- xyplot(Col2+Col3~Time, Data, type="spline")
Plot3 <- xyplot(Col1+Col3~Time, Data, type="spline")
Plot4 <- xyplot(Col3+Col4~Time, Data, type="spline")

grid.arrange(Plot1,Plot2,Plot3,Plot4, ncol=2)
```

Comment: Build the plots in an environment where `my.setup` is the current `trellis.par`.

Comment: @DWin. Sorry, could you be more specific?

Comment: lattice has built-in functionality to arrange multiple plots in a page (even multiple pages), that may be a better approach. `?lattice:::print.trellis`

Comment: I' aware of print(plot1,pos,split). I found it problematic by finding the position every time I want arbitrary (i.e. 2x2, 3x3, 3x4 etc.) multi-plots.

Comment: please post a minimal self-contained reproducible example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it's got something to do with the `plot.trellis` method not finding the global theme settings when it's wrapped in `gridExtra::drawDetails.lattice`. I don't understand these lattice options, but as far as I recall you can specify them explicitly at the plot level too,

```
pl = list(Plot1, Plot2, Plot3, Plot4)
# do.call(grid.arrange, c(pl, nrow=1))
do.call(grid.arrange, c(lapply(pl, update, par.settings=newSet), list(nrow=1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Btw. how would this look like in case I have 3 plots and I want them horizontally instead vertically? With the above example, providing pl=list(Plot1,Plot2,Plot3), the plot is vertical (bellow each other). Thanks.

Comment: But this won't use my current setting-newSet, the lines are in default colours.

Comment: Actually, the command: grid.arrange(Plot1,Plot2,Plot3, ncol=3) when printed into pdf (but in R window it shows the default setup) uses the newSet instructions, hence my issue is solved. Thx.