# modifying main, axis, and axis label font size in `effects' package plots with `grid.arrange()` in `R`

Tags: r, plot, font-size, gridextra

I'm using the `effects` package in `R` to plot the effect on response variable of specific predictors in multiple linear regression. I'm trying to plot several of such plots in a single image.

When I plot several of them, the main text and axis text font size is too large, making it impossible to fit all the text (instead I have to use cryptic numbers and abbreviations, which isn't very helpful).

I want to make the main, axis and axis label text smaller.

Now, since the `effects`package uses `lattice` to generate plots, I'm using the lattice way of modifying font size i.e. `trellis.par.set()`. The weird thing is that it modifies single plots as specified, but when it pulls them together with the last command `grid.arrange()`, the values revert back to default.

I'm quite puzzled by this and have not been able to find a solution to this online. Any advice? Thanks in advance!

[image: Here <code>trellis.par.set</code> doesn't work.]
[image: Here `trellis.par.set() works.']

```
require(gridExtra)
require(lattice)
require(effects)

trellis.par.get()
trellis.par.set(list(par.xlab.text = list(cex=0.5),
                     par.ylab.text = list(cex=0.5),
                     par.main.text = list(col = "blue", cex=0.5)))

logit.plot = plot(Effect(c("LogitABCD.log.std"), logit.item.slope.mod), xlab = "Log Cond. Prob." , ylab = "Log RT", main="A.1 Pos. CP", ylim = c(6.0, 7.5))

logit.neg.plot = plot(Effect(c("LogitABCD.neg.log.std"), logit.neg.item.slope.mod), xlab = "Neg. Log Cond. Prob." , ylab = "Log RT", main="A.2 Neg. CP", ylim = c(6.0, 7.5))

MI.plot = plot(Effect(c("MIABCD.log.std"), MI.item.slope.mod), xlab = "Log MI" , ylab = "Log RT", main="   B.1 Pos. MI", ylim = c(6.0, 7.5))

MI.neg.plot = plot(Effect(c("MIABCD.neg.log.std"), MI.neg.item.slope.mod), xlab = "Neg. Log MI" , ylab = "Log RT", main="   B.2 Neg. MI", ylim = c(6.0, 7.5))

grid.arrange(logit.plot, MI.plot, logit.neg.plot, MI.neg.plot, ncol = 2)
```

I also tried to solve the issue by adapting a solution used in a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540129/lattice-multiple-plots-in-one-window), but that didn't work either. What I did was to preface the individual plot-making code with the following:

```
newSet = col.whitebg() 
newSet$superpose.symbol$cex = 0.5
newSet$superpose.symbol$col = "blue"
```

And then after the I call grid.arrange(), I inserted the following code:

```
pl = list(logit.plot, MI.plot, logit.neg.plot, MI.neg.plot)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(lapply(pl, update, par.settings=newSet), list(nrow=2)))
```

Still, no luck. Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple lattice plots with gridExtra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419756/multiple-lattice-plots-with-gridextra)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this resource. I edited the question to show that the post you suggested did not solve my problem.