# How to regroup and count elements within a column

Tags: sql, group-by, syntax-error, hue, case-when

I have data for tasks given out in supermarkets organized by:

- task_id - each individual task has a unique id
- store_id - each store has a unique number identifying it
- week_start - start of the week when the task was assigned
- category - the type of task (ketchup, mustard, hotdogs, bacon,...)
- busy - a true/false variable for if it was predicted to be busy that week
- manager - name of manager for the store

Currently the data is organized by task_id (individual task) I would like to have it organized by store & week and then count the amount of tasks assigned in a category in each week.

Additionally the category column is currently too granular meaning I would like to group hotdogs, bacon, turkey, etc as meat and ketchup, mustard, mayo as sauce.

I am essentially trying to mirror results of what would be in a pivot table with store_id,week_start,busy, & manager being the rows, category as the columns, and then sum category as the data in the middle. But in this case category made less granular with an index(match function.

I tried running something similar to

''''SQL

```
SELECT store_id, week_start, busy, mananger
COUNT(CASE WHEN category = 'hotdog' or 'bacon' or 'turkey') AS MEAT, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN category = 'ketchup' or 'mustard') AS Sauce
FROM table1 
GROUP BY store_id, week_start;
```

but The error I receive is:

AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 2:undefined: 'ketchup' AS Sauce) 
 ^ Encountered: AS Expected: AND, BETWEEN, DIV, ILIKE, IN, IREGEXP, IS, LIKE, NOT, OR, REGEXP, RLIKE, THEN CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Comment: Concerning **hexbinplot** (deleted question), this solution might work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18419756/6574038. All you have to do is adjust your par settings.

Comment: thank you! I deleted the question since I found it very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808810/how-to-arrange-multiple-hexbin-plots-together-in-r?noredirect=1#comment100171857_56808810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count values, then I prefer `sum()` over `count()`.  Either way, you need a properly formed `case` expression:

```
SELECT store_id, week_start, mananger,
       SUM(CASE WHEN category IN ('hotdog','bacon', 'turkey') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MEAT, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN category IN ('ketchup', 'mustard') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sauce
FROM table1 
GROUP BY store_id, week_start;
```

I also removed `busy` from the `SELECT` list.  The unaggregated columns in `SELECT` should be compatible with the columns in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the syntax help it fixed the issue. Is there any way to include the mananger/busy data along side the summed totals for the week?

Comment: @LiamHaller . . . You can add `busy` to both the `select` and the `group by`.