# How to arrange multiple Hexbin plots together in r?

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

I have four separate Hexbin Plots that I would like to view together in one frame.

I tired using par(mfrow...) to no avail.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

hexbinplot(Sales ~ employee...)

hexbinplot(Sales ~ Quality...)

hexbinplot(Sales ~ Weather...)

hexbinplot(Sales ~ Year...)
```

I suspect the answer may be in panel.hexbinplot but I have been unable to find any resources that talk about linking multiple distinct graphs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting 3 graphs in a 2-1 layout in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231830/plotting-3-graphs-in-a-2-1-layout-in-r)

Comment: I tried adding:  ` layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4) ,2,2, byrow=TRUE))
layout.show(n=4)`   but it still plotted them as individual graphs

Comment: I found the answer from similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808810/how-to-arrange-multiple-hexbin-plots-together-in-r?noredirect=1#comment100171857_56808810